# CSS isolation in Blazor server-side

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side app which I created with NET5 and then upgraded to NET6. It still uses the old `_Host.cshtml`.

I added a `css` file to a razor page and then I added the following line to the `_Host.cshtml` file:

```
<link href="My.App.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But when I run the app, the page's styles are not being applied.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you have in the browser network tab about the request for this file?

Comment: Status Code 304. It*s being loaded in the correct order and the custom styles are also there.

Comment: 304 is globally meaning that the file is loaded through cache. Try reloading your page having the browser network tab opened with disable cache checkbox enabled.

Comment: Ok it looks like it's working and that my styles are wrong and therefore not being applied.